# Ошибка при выводе на консоль после десериализация List, со вложенной структурой

Tags: c#, сериализация, десериализация

Есть list классов со вложенной структурой. Вот Экземпляр класса родителя(Классы наследники почти не отличаются).

```
[Serializable(), XmlInclude(typeof(Triangle)), XmlInclude(typeof(Quadrangle)),XmlInclude(typeof(Top))]
    public abstract class Figure : Comp
    {
        string name;
        Top a, b, c, d;
        Top[] Tops;
        public Color colorFigure;

        public List<Figure> FigureList = new List<Figure>();



        public Figure()
        { }



        public Figure(Top a, Top b, Top c, Color colorFigure)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
            ColorFigure = colorFigure;
            Tops = new Top[3] { A, B, C };
        }



        public Figure(Top a, Top b, Top c, Top d, Color colorFigure)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
            C = c;
            D = d;
            ColorFigure = colorFigure;
            Tops = new Top[4] { A, B, C, D };
        }



        public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
        public Top A { get => a; set => a = value; }
        public Top B { get => b; set => b = value; }
        public Top C { get => c; set => c = value; }
        public Top D { get => d; set => d = value; }
        public Color ColorFigure { get => colorFigure; set => colorFigure = value; }



        public abstract double Area();

        public abstract double Perimeter();



        public void ShowInfo()
        {

            var cc = ClosestConsoleColor(ColorFigure.R, ColorFigure.G, ColorFigure.B);

            Console.ForegroundColor = cc;

            Console.ForegroundColor = cc;
            Console.WriteLine(Name);
            Console.WriteLine($"Color {ColorFigure}");
            Console.WriteLine("Coordinates");
            foreach (Top top in Tops)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{top.X}, {top.Y}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Perimeter = {Perimeter()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Area = {Area()}");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        //это не мой код, ядом не надо поливать
        protected ConsoleColor ClosestConsoleColor(byte r, byte g, byte b) 
        {
            ConsoleColor ret = 0;
            double rr = r, gg = g, bb = b, delta = double.MaxValue;

            foreach (ConsoleColor cc in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)))
            {
                var n = cc.ToString();//Enum.GetName(typeof(ConsoleColor), cc);
                var c = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(n == "DarkYellow" ? "Orange" : n); // bug fix
                var t = Math.Pow(c.R - rr, 2.0) + Math.Pow(c.G - gg, 2.0) + Math.Pow(c.B - bb, 2.0);
                if (t == 0.0)
                    return cc;
                if (t < delta)
                {
                    delta = t;
                    ret = cc;
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
        //Теперь снова мой) 


        public double SideLength(Top a, Top b)
        {
            return Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow((a.X - b.X), 2)) + (Math.Pow((a.Y - b.Y), 2)));
        }



        public List<Figure> ReadAndDeserialize()
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Figure>));
            using (var sr = new StreamReader("searilize.txt"))
            {
                return (List<Figure>)serializer.Deserialize(sr);
            }
        }



        public void SerializeAndSave(List<Figure> data)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Figure>));
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("searilize.txt", true))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, data);
            }
        }



        public void SerializeAndRewritingSave(List<Figure> data)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Figure>));
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("searilize.txt"))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(sw, data);
            }
        }
    }



    [Serializable]
    public struct Top
    {
        int x, y;

        public Top(int x, int y) : this()
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public int X { get => x; set => x = value; }

        public int Y { get => y; set => y = value; }
    }
}
```

Сериализация List проходит не полностью, во первых не сохраняется цвет экземпляра класса. Во вторых после десериализации метод "public void ShowInfo()" выводит ошибку "System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. <Временное локальное типа "FigureLib.Top[]"> было null."
 на строке

```
foreach (Top top in Tops)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{top.X}, {top.Y}");
            }
```

Как исправить? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта. <Временное локальное типа "FigureLib.Top[]"> было null` это разве не дает ясно понять о сути проблемы?

Comment: Я понимаю, что тут написано. Я не понимаю, почему мне выдает эту ошибку, так как до сериализации все работает исправно. И вопрос с цветом также остаётся открытым.

Comment: Вопрос с foreach в методе ShowInfo() решена, дело в том, что я не учел что сериализацию не проходят приватные свойства. Осталось решить проблему сериализации цвета.

Comment: Я бы написал свой класс, специально предназначенный для сериализпции\десериализации и свой класс для хранения цвета в нем. Мне кажется, что встроенный класс для цвета просто не поддерживает сериализацию. Ну и вообще я сторонник того, что сериализовать нужно только свои классы.

Comment: Color относится к System.Drawing. И да он не сериаизуется. Ответы на свои вопросы нашёл, все напишу в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак. Основных вопроса было два. 
Первый - ошибка в ShowInfo() после десериализации, в частности на моменте исполнения foreach (Top top in Tops).
Второй - потеря значения Color при сериализации.

Ответ на первый вопрос. Дело в том, что значения структур Top сохранялось, но я не добавил модификатор доступа к массив Top[], из-за чего он был приватный(по умолчанию) и не сериализовался. Добавив модификатор доступа public к Top[], все заработало.

Ответ на второй вопрос. Если я правильно вычитал, то System.Drawing.Color является иммутабельным(не понял правда в чем это выражено), то есть Color будет readonly, из-за чего и не сериализуестя. Ответ нашел вот тут https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2444304.html
Легкая модификация

```
 [XmlIgnore]
        public Color ColorFigure { get => colorFigure; set => colorFigure = value; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Method to serialize color
        /// </summary>
        [XmlElement("Color")] // Или Attribute
        public int ColorSerialized
        {
            get => ColorFigure.ToArgb();
            set => ColorFigure = Color.FromArgb(value);
        }
```

и у меня все работает.